# Pseudo-inverse of the subset of identity matrix

Tags: transpose, pseudoinverse

I have the identity matrix $I_N\in\Re^{N\times N}$.

Now I consider matrix $A\in\Re^{N\times (N-1)}$ which is composed by a generic subset of of N-1 columns of matrix $I_N$.

I find out in my MATLAB code that this property always hold: pinv(A) is equal to $A^T$.

How can I prove that fact?

Best regards.

Comment: What is a "generic" subset ?

Comment: Did you try showing that $A^T$ satisfies the four defining properties of the pseudo inverse https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One proof is as follows. As is noted [on the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Moore%E2%80%93Penrose_inverse#Definition) for the pseudoinverse, if $A$ has linearly independent columns, then its pseudoinverse is given by
$$
A^+ = (A^TA)^{-1}A^T.
$$
On the other hand, if $A$ is formed using the columns of the identity matrix, then $A$ must have orthonormal columns, which means that $A^TA = I_{N-1}$. Conclude that
$$
A^+ = I_{N-1}A^T = A^T,
$$
which is what we wanted.